# Interior wall help--temporary

Tags: walls, interior, temporary

Attempting to build possibly temporary walls in finished basement to construct a bedroom in a currently large open area.It appears I can tie into ceiling joists, however the floor is ceramic tile and I dont want to pull it up or put holes in it. One idea I saw was to use sill tape to get the bottom plate to stay in place. Construction adhesive would be more or less permanent. Any other suggestions??  It will be 2 walls connected by an angled wall 2'(also new), with a door on one side.  Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that a bedroom has certain minimum egress requirements. Typically this means an external door or a large window (with additional requirements - bottom of window has to be within a certain height above the floor). When building a basement bedroom you should keep these requirements in mind.

Comment: Construction adhesive will work great if you just put a dab every few feet on the grout lines and then place your bottom plate.

Comment: Sounds good with adhesive on grout lines every few feet--will be able to get bottom plate up later on?   True regarding bedroom egress--this is due to a very hasty need for multigenerational space.  We are needing to enlarge a window in the "real" bedroom for son for egress, knew of size requirement but hadnt heard of height from floor-will have to look into that.   This particular area I'm needing to wall off could be more of a study (yes with a bed for now)  Thanks much for the help!     I'm planning on 2x3 studs as well--since none will be weight bearing.